# [ros2cli] How can I get a list of lifecycle nodes from packages?

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know there is no `ros2cli` command which lists lifecycle nodes from ROS2 packages installed. Do you plan to add something like that? Is there some workaround to get lifecycle nodes on a system without need to start the nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296961/%5Bros2cli%5D-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-lifecycle-nodes-from-packages?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no such command at the moment. Also that kind of information is not available anywhere. A package doesn't declare anywhere what nodes it installs and if they are using a life cycle. I don't think there is any plan to require packages to "register" their nodes anywhere.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-07-12**:
Are there example lifecycle nodes already?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-12**:
https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/4e3f5eb1a0d8fff34e91f787b323faed4aa0ef34/lifecycle